# R: Trim whitespace within brackets

Tags: r, trim

How can whitespace within brackets be trimmed?

```
x <- c("the li7(li7, p)b13 reaction")
```

In this particular case, it should only remove the whitespace between the comma and the p, but I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: Use `gsub` with the appropriate regular expression.

Comment: ... been trying ...

Comment: If it is only this one application, try `x <- gsub(", p", ",p", x, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: no, it's a pattern, not just this application ;)

Comment: and the pattern is always a whitespace within brackets?

Comment: yes, always whitespace within brackets

Comment: I don't know how to define the pattern...

Comment: @hyco is it always one set of brackets or nested?

Comment: @sebastian-c please see my answer to Leo P. below. Data can also be like `x <- c("the c13(d, a)b11 and c13(d, t)c12 reactions")` But not brackets inside brackets.

Comment: I see. Is there any situation where spaces in brackets should be preserved (quotes, for example)?

Comment: no special cases as far as I can foresee (no preservation). only multiple bracksts per string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cases <-c(
  "(a,b)",
  "(a, b)",
  "( a, b)",
  "a(a, b)",
  "a (a, b)",
  "a (a, b) a(a,b) a(a,b )"
)

gsub("[[:space:]](?=[^()]*\\))", "", cases, perl = TRUE)
[1] "(a,b)"                 "(a,b)"                 "(a,b)"                
[4] "a(a,b)"                "a (a,b)"               "a (a,b) a(a,b) a(a,b)"
```

The regex works as follows: when it finds a space, it looks ahead for a right parenthesis. If it finds any other parentheses on the way, it stops and moves on until it finds a space with none. It the replaces that with an empty string.

Comment: Nice, could you break down that regular expression? And can this be done with the R-way of regexp and you are just more used to perl, or is it not possible without using the perl-like regexp?

Comment: Nah, you need the lookaheads which come with perl.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found a solution using `str_extract()` in the `stringr`-package.

```
gsub("\\(+.*[[:blank:]]+.*\\)+", 
 gsub("[[:blank:]]", "", 
  str_extract(x, "\\(+.*[[:blank:]]+.*\\)+")),x)
```

This uses `gsub()` to search for a string pattern with a whitespace within brackets, then uses another gsub to replace it with the extracted part without the whitespace.

Edit: If your pattern within the brackets consists of something not covered by the `[[:graph:]]`-family, you might need to change that part of the expression.

Edit of edit: switched the `[[:graph:]]` for `.`, so this should now work on pretty much anything.

Comment: Many thanks so far! I must specify the problem: Multiple brackets within a string are possible. Like `x <- c("the c13(d, a)b11 and c13(d, t)c12 reactions")` Unfortunately, in this case your trick to extract and replace does not work. We're at the beginning again.